# Performance tuning methods in Bulk Updates

Tags: database, performance, oracle10g

I need to update 2 million records in 120 tables. I have created indexes on each table since the same column is referred in where clause and in update statement. Each table has 100 000 records on an average. I have disabled the foreign key constraints before update.

For this I have written a procedure where it will fetch the records and run the update statements. From the blogs I came to know Bulk Collect & FORALL is good option in oracle, but there is only small difference in time that I can see to run the update statements. Are they any other approach to increase the performance and reduce the time to update the records into the tables?

Comment: Can the updates be done in a set-based fashion (i.e. 120 set-based update statements)?

Comment: Yes you are right Justin Cave